# having trouble selecting the clicked href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

```
<li class="treeview">
  <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-laptop"></i>
    <span>Configuration</span>
    <span class="pull-right-container">
      <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
    </span>
  </a>
  <ul class="treeview-menu" style="display: none;">
    <li>
      <a href="/Home/General"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> General</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Please help me in selecting the clicked element. I tried the below but it's not working.

```
 $("ul.treeview").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('acive');
});
```

Comment: You did not state any problem in your question

Comment: I think you meant ul.treeview-menu in your selector. Also there's a typo in removeClass -> active is spelled acive

Comment: `treeview` is li class not ul better check the html markup properly

Answer (score 0):

You assign your click event to wrong element. Try:

```
$("ul.treeview-menu").siblings().click(function (e) {
  $(this).find('a') // do whatever with it
});
```

This way you select `<a>` inside the menu.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $("li.treeview").click(function() {
   $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('acive');
 });
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="treeview">
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-laptop"></i>
      <span>Configuration</span>
      <span class="pull-right-container">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                </span>
    </a>
    <ul class="treeview-menu" style="display: none;">
      <li><a href="/Home/General"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> General</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/Home/Test"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Test</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Check this one

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to select the a tag within the list item you clicked you could use

```
$("ul .treeview").click(function () {
  $("ul .treeview a").removeClass("active")
  var x = $(this).find('a');
  x.addClass("active")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below Code that might help.

```
$("ul .treeview").click(function () {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Remove active class for all same level `li` and add active class to clicked one.